# Why is the value of a local variable being set to nil inside of a lua closure?

Tags: lua, neovim

It is my understanding that lua can handle higher order functions and that locals should be captured by closures. Yet I'm running into a situation where the variable `plugin_name` does not seem to be captured inside of the closure.

```lua
local cfg = function(plugin_name) 
    print(plugin_name) -- <-- has value
    return function()
        -- plugin_name is nil at this point if
        -- this closure is invoked by Packer
        require("cfg." .. plugin_name)
    end
end
```

Is there something I need to do to indicate that `plugin_name` needs to be retained?

**Edit:**

The issue arises when the closure is invoked by [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim).

Simply calling it:

```lua
local cfg = function(plugin_name) 
    print(plugin_name)
    return function()
        print(plugin_name)
        local p= "cfg." .. plugin_name
        print(p)
    end
end 

cfg("example")()
```

works as expected.

Yet I don't understand why the reference would become nil once passed to another package.

```lua
local status_ok, packer = pcall(require, "packer")

local cfg = function(plugin_name) 
    return function()
        local p= "cfg." .. plugin_name
        require(p)
    end
end 

return packer.startup(function(use)
    use { "folke/which-key.nvim", config = function() require("cfg.which-key") end } -- works
    -- use { "folke/which-key.nvim", config = cfg("which-key") } -- does not work
end
```

Comment: Please show the code where you call this lambda function. Provide an [mcve] that shows the problem in question.

Comment: @NicolBolas it is being called by [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim). I'm digging through their source to try and find where it is called.

Comment: It shouldn't matter who is calling it. If the problem manifests as you claim that it does, then it should be pretty simple as to how to exhibit the problem: `cfg("something")()` should print "something" followed by "nil". Otherwise, the problem is elsewhere, and your code should be updated appropriately.

Comment: @NicolBolas so simply calling it works as expected. I don't understand how the context of the call would matter either, but it seems to?

Comment: @Chance - Please post the code which proves that `the reference would become nil`.

Comment: I think it is because packer will compile the config into byte string (`string.dump()`), the closure will lose its context once the function is dumped and reloaded. Do not do fancy stuff in config, just require your plugin config, unless you are lua guru and can figure out how to do all this correctly. Please check `packer_compiled.lua` to check the compiled version of your packer config.

Comment: @jdhao if you submit an answer with that, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Chance Add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because packer will compile the config into byte string (using `string.dump()`), the closure will lose its context (it is called `upvalue` in lua) once the function is dumped and reloaded. Do not do fancy stuff in config, just require your plugin config. Also please check `packer_compiled.lua` to check the compiled version of your packer config.

Regarding the `upvalue` issue, there are some issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14509814/6064933), [here](https://lua-l.lua.narkive.com/0sU008tT/string-dump-closure).